# How to open two specific view controller on buttons click in notification content extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, push-notification

I'm using the notification content extension. In the extensionViewController, there are two buttons for different actions, first button to move to the firstViewController(FirstVC) and second button to move to the secondViewController(SecondVC).
I'm using storyboard id for this, then also it is showing error (use of undeclared type FirstVC).

`let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first") as! FirstVC 
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

If there is any solution for this then please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first") as! FirstVC   
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Where is this FirstVC ??. You should be casting as Your viewController name not as UIviewController.

Comment: please review my comment again.

Comment: Don't post code in comments, update your question instead.

Comment: Have you imported UIKit ?

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding this is notification content extension's storyboard not main storyboard, that's why it show error because the FirstVC is in main storyboard

Answer (score 0):

As UINotification Content extension is another target, so you need to add the FirstVC & secondVC to UINotificationContent Extension target. Then you need to initialize your storyboard with name then use the above code. Hope this will resolve your problem.

How to add file to target? 
select you file (e.g. FirstVC) then on identity inspector select file symbmol then tick the target membership for file